# What statistical analysis should I use

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, spss, nonparametric

I have been measuring flux of CO2 in (mmol m-2 d-1) from two different rivers and I now want to do a statistical analysis using IBM SPSS but Im not sure where to start. One lake is showing negative gas, the reason for this is because the lake as acted like a sink for the CO2.

I have made a histogram first see how the data looks like, as you can see in the figure I’ve added additional with a label of the data. As mention above the negative data is from one lake and the positive data is from another lake

The label show what lake I have studied, what time I started the measurement and when I stopped measuring, the column daytime (1) describes when the sun rise up and nighttime (2) describes when there is sunset, T_air oC and T_H2O describes describe the temperature in water and air during the measurement.

What I want to accomplish with the statistical analysis is first to understand how I should think before I start to analyzing;

- What is the statistically different within the two lakes?
- What is the statistically different are there between the two lakes?
  and
- How does the correlation between FCO2 and temperature?

Is there anyone who can come with some suggestion what statistically analysis I should use for each thing I want to accomplish? I have from somewhere I should use a one-way Anova but not sure where to start thinking.
[image: Histogram of data]

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
lake & Initital sampling (data and time) & Final sampling (Date and time) & Daytime (1) nighttime (2) & T\_air oC & T\_H2O & FCO2\_mmol m-2 d-1 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-16 18:35 & 2022-03-16 20:18 & 1 & 4.5            & 4.5   & -2.29507 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-16 20:33 & 2022-03-16 22:15 & 2 & 4.35           & 4.35  & -2.48989 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-16 22:35 & 2022-03-17 00:16 & 2 & 4.22           & 4.22  & -2.52834 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 00:35 & 2022-03-17 02:18 & 2 & 4.02           & 4.02  & -2.4524  \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 02:34 & 2022-03-17 04:13 & 2 & 4.12           & 4.12  & -2.47989 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 04:38 & 2022-03-17 06:15 & 1 & 4.36           & 4.36  & -2.18617 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 06:34 & 2022-03-17 08:16 & 1 & 5.35           & 5.35  & -1.86178 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 08:35 & 2022-03-17 10:17 & 1 & 6.07           & 6.07  & -2.42144 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 10:34 & 2022-03-17 12:18 & 1 & 7.44           & 7.44  & -2.52941 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 12:34 & 2022-03-17 14:17 & 1 & 8.16           & 8.16  & -2.21627 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 14:33 & 2022-03-17 16:19 & 1 & 7.97           & 7.97  & -2.55553 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 16:39 & 2022-03-17 18:17 & 1 & 7.52           & 7.52  & -2.0844  \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 18:34 & 2022-03-17 20:17 & 1 & 7.54           & 7.54  & -2.43122 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 20:34 & 2022-03-17 22:17 & 2 & 8.06           & 8.06  & -1.96291 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 22:35 & 2022-03-18 00:18 & 2 & 7.41           & 7.41  & -1.54653 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 00:38 & 2022-03-18 02:18 & 2 & 7.60           & 7.6   & -1.591   \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 02:35 & 2022-03-18 04:17 & 2 & 7.42           & 7.42  & -1.99879 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 04:36 & 2022-03-18 06:16 & 1 & 7.02           & 7.02  & -1.44514 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 06:35 & 2022-03-18 08:18 & 1 & 8.12           & 8.12  & -1.82221 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 08:33 & 2022-03-18 10:17 & 1 & 8.97           & 8.97  & -2.30534 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 10:34 & 2022-03-18 12:18 & 1 & 11.63          & 11.63 & -1.49893 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 12:37 & 2022-03-18 14:17 & 1 & 10.75          & 10.75 & -2.20711 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 14:38 & 2022-03-18 16:18 & 1 & 11.57          & 11.57 & -1.80309 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 16:41 & 2022-03-18 18:17 & 1 & 8.66           & 8.66  & -1.67234 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 18:37 & 2022-03-18 20:15 & 1 & 6.18           & 6.18  & -1.3983  \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 20:37 & 2022-03-18 22:17 & 2 & 5.02           & 5.02  & -1.32119 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 22:34 & 2022-03-19 00:17 & 2 & 4.50           & 4.5   & -1.45022 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 00:34 & 2022-03-19 02:17 & 2 & 4.74           & 4.74  & -1.49234 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 02:35 & 2022-03-19 04:18 & 2 & 4.75           & 4.75  & -1.16388 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 04:35 & 2022-03-19 06:18 & 1 & 4.34           & 4.34  & -0.87719 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 10:33 & 2022-03-19 12:17 & 1 & 13.33          & 13.33 & -1.04391 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 12:34 & 2022-03-19 14:18 & 1 & 11.86          & 11.86 & -1.15754 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 14:37 & 2022-03-19 16:18 & 1 & 14.32          & 14.32 & -1.3017  \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 16:35 & 2022-03-19 18:18 & 1 & 7.77           & 7.77  & -1.41987 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 18:33 & 2022-03-19 20:18 & 1 & 5.49           & 5.49  & -1.20405 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 20:35 & 2022-03-19 22:16 & 2 & 4.92           & 4.92  & -1.29523 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 08:34 & 2022-03-20 10:13 & 1 & 13.10          & 13.1  & -2.09114 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 10:34 & 2022-03-20 12:16 & 1 & 12.37          & 12.37 & -1.80007 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 12:32 & 2022-03-20 14:18 & 1 & 12.81          & 12.81 & -1.55716 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 14:34 & 2022-03-20 16:17 & 1 & 15.58          & 15.58 & -1.86034 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 16:34 & 2022-03-20 18:17 & 1 & 9.39           & 9.39  & -1.90103 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 18:33 & 2022-03-20 20:18 & 1 & 5.44           & 5.44  & -1.53041 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 20:35 & 2022-03-20 22:14 & 2 & 4.67           & 4.67  & -1.79374 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 22:37 & 2022-03-21 00:17 & 2 & 4.48           & 4.48  & -1.01154 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-29 21:55 & 2022-03-29 23:35 & 2 & \textbf{4.44}  & 4.44  & 2.853022 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-29 23:56 & 2022-03-30 01:35 & 2 & \textbf{3.51}  & 3.51  & 2.15667  \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 01:56 & 2022-03-30 03:34 & 2 & \textbf{2.38}  & 2.38  & 2.231913 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 03:54 & 2022-03-30 05:35 & 2 & \textbf{2.16}  & 2.16  & 1.759635 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 05:53 & 2022-03-30 07:35 & 1 & \textbf{3.7}   & 3.7   & 1.001419 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 07:56 & 2022-03-30 09:35 & 1 & \textbf{7.8}   & 7.8   & 0.960555 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 09:53 & 2022-03-30 11:35 & 1 & \textbf{9.98}  & 9.98  & 1.991259 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 11:56 & 2022-03-30 13:34 & 1 & \textbf{10.25} & 10.25 & 1.517868 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 13:51 & 2022-03-30 15:34 & 1 & \textbf{10.2}  & 10.2  & 1.821623 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 15:53 & 2022-03-30 17:35 & 1 & \textbf{9.63}  & 9.63  & 1.741887 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 17:54 & 2022-03-30 19:35 & 1 & \textbf{6.38}  & 6.38  & 2.141064 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 19:55 & 2022-03-30 21:35 & 2 & \textbf{4.96}  & 4.96  & 2.685757 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 21:56 & 2022-03-30 23:35 & 2 & \textbf{4}     & 4     & 2.923715 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 23:52 & 2022-03-31 01:11 & 2 & \textbf{3.54}  & 3.54  & 3.316899 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 01:52 & 2022-03-31 03:34 & 2 & \textbf{2.99}  & 2.99  & 1.681422 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 07:55 & 2022-03-31 09:35 & 1 & \textbf{10.4}  & 10.4  & 1.361125 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 13:58 & 2022-03-31 15:34 & 1 & \textbf{12.34} & 12.34 & 0.734101 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 15:55 & 2022-03-31 17:35 & 1 & \textbf{8.69}  & 8.69  & 0.947828 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 17:54 & 2022-03-31 19:35 & 1 & \textbf{6.6}   & 6.6   & 0.512018 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 19:53 & 2022-03-31 21:35 & 2 & \textbf{4.82}  & 4.82  & 1.261292 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 06:04 & 2022-04-01 07:35 & 1 & \textbf{4.9}   & 4.9   & 1.77807  \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 09:54 & 2022-04-01 11:34 & 1 & \textbf{7.73}  & 7.73  & 1.738892 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 12:02 & 2022-04-01 13:22 & 1 & \textbf{9.9}   & 9.9   & 1.109685 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 13:51 & 2022-04-01 15:35 & 1 & \textbf{9.06}  & 9.06  & 1.232822 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 15:56 & 2022-04-01 17:36 & 1 & \textbf{8.57}  & 8.57  & 0.857767 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 17:56 & 2022-04-01 19:34 & 1 & \textbf{4.62}  & 4.62  & 1.44003  \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 19:53 & 2022-04-01 21:36 & 2 & \textbf{2.78}  & 2.78  & 2.121573 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 22:04 & 2022-04-01 23:24 & 2 & \textbf{2.9}   & 2.9   & 2.611131 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 00:01 & 2022-04-02 01:36 & 2 & \textbf{1.99}  & 1.99  & 1.989111 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 01:56 & 2022-04-02 03:36 & 2 & \textbf{1.6}   & 1.6   & 1.889324 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 03:56 & 2022-04-02 05:35 & 2 & \textbf{1.51}  & 1.51  & 1.239421 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 05:54 & 2022-04-02 07:34 & 1 & \textbf{2.73}  & 2.73  & 0.908215 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 07:58 & 2022-04-02 08:48 & 1 & \textbf{4.94}  & 4.94  & 0.72762  \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 10:04 & 2022-04-02 11:26 & 1 & \textbf{11.35} & 11.35 & 0.634685 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 13:59 & 2022-04-02 15:37 & 1 & \textbf{9.45}  & 9.45  & 0.851654 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 15:54 & 2022-04-02 17:38 & 1 & \textbf{8.7}   & 8.7   & 1.322688 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 17:58 & 2022-04-02 19:38 & 1 & \textbf{6.64}  & 6.64  & 1.169257 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 19:54 & 2022-04-02 21:39 & 2 & \textbf{5.25}  & 5.25  & 1.483866 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 22:00 & 2022-04-02 23:40 & 2 & \textbf{4.87}  & 4.87  & 1.363993 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 00:04 & 2022-04-03 01:36 & 2 & \textbf{4.78}  & 4.78  & 1.777732 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 02:00 & 2022-04-03 03:40 & 2 & \textbf{4.8}   & 4.8   & 1.488471 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 03:56 & 2022-04-03 05:40 & 2 & \textbf{4.54}  & 4.54  & 0.842322 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 05:57 & 2022-04-03 07:41 & 1 & \textbf{5.12}  & 5.12  & 1.25267  \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 07:58 & 2022-04-03 09:40 & 1 & \textbf{7.82}  & 7.82  & 1.638629 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 10:02 & 2022-04-03 11:42 & 1 & \textbf{10.2}  & 10.2  & 1.543532 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 11:59 & 2022-04-03 13:42 & 1 & \textbf{11.4}  & 11.4  & 1.734148 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 14:02 & 2022-04-03 15:42 & 1 & \textbf{10.1}  & 10.1  & 2.221091 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 16:01 & 2022-04-03 17:20 & 1 & \textbf{9.2}   & 9.2   & 2.092675 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 19:59 & 2022-04-03 21:43 & 2 & \textbf{6.69}  & 6.69  & 2.461853 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 22:03 & 2022-04-03 23:38 & 2 & \textbf{6.34}  & 6.34  & 3.361063 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 00:01 & 2022-04-04 01:43 & 2 & \textbf{6.36}  & 6.36  & 4.282346 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 02:02 & 2022-04-04 03:45 & 2 & \textbf{7.02}  & 7.02  & 5.178646 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 04:08 & 2022-04-04 05:45 & 1 & \textbf{7}     & 7     & 1.177135 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 06:08 & 2022-04-04 07:44 & 1 & \textbf{6.58}  & 6.58  & 1.053295 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 08:07 & 2022-04-04 09:24 & 1 & \textbf{6.74}  & 6.74  & 1.20853 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}